# I can't close the fig from matplotlib.pyplot in jupyter note book

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

windows python 3.7.3
matplotlib 3.0.3

```
for raw_name in img_list: 
            img1 = np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, raw_name)))
            img2 = np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, raw_name.replace('.jpg', '.png'))))
            f, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2, dpi=400, frameon=False, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [6, 1]})
            plt.ion()
            axarr[0].imshow(img1)
            plt.axis('off')
            axarr[1].imshow(img2)
            plt.axis('off')

            plt.show(block=False)
            plt.close('all')
```

I want to show the images in every loop and refresh the output by closing the plot in the end of every loop. But the result just showed images one by one.
can anyone tell me how to close the plot in jupyter notebook ?

Comment: If ypou want to clear the cell output you can use `clear_output(wait  = True)`. Import from `IPython.display` and insert it whenever you want to clear the cell output, for instance after plt.close()

Comment: thank it works! but why plt.close() didn't work?

Comment: plt.close() closes the interactivity with the plot, therefore further plots will not be plotted in that same figure, but the figure remains visible.